# Need callback return value as well as pass parameter to that same callback function

Tags: jquery

I am calling an internal confirmDialog box which uses a callback because what happens next depends on users response.  This works just fine.

```
confirmDialog('Record Locked', 'Record(s) locked by ' + locksheldby + 'Do you want to acquire record(s)', ConfirmRecordLocks);

function ConfirmRecordLocks(confirmed) {
    console.log('what is confirmed', confirmed)
    ...
}
```

But along with that I would like to pass an object containing additional information that was already retrieved from database without having to go fetch it again.  I do not want to use a global variable.  Is this possible?

Everything I found related to additional parameters applies to ajax. I've tried a few variations that I did find but no luck.  The first parameter contains the object but not the user's response.  The second parameter is empty

```
confirmDialog('Record Locked', 'Record(s) locked by ' + locksheldby + '.  Do you want to acquire record(s)?', function() { ConfirmRecordLocks(lockdata)});


function ConfirmRecordLocks(confirmed, lockdata) {
    console.log('what is confirmed', confirmed)
    console.log('what is lockdata', lockdata)
    ...
}
```

Comment: why do you need to pass an object in your function? You can just use the object in this function without passing it as long as it is in the same confirmDialog scope

Comment: They are in 2 different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Thy this:

```
confirmDialog('Record Locked', 'Record(s) locked by ' + locksheldby + '.  Do you want to acquire record(s)?', function(confirmed) { ConfirmRecordLocks(confirmed, lockdata)});


function ConfirmRecordLocks(confirmed, lockdata) {
    console.log('what is confirmed', confirmed)
    console.log('what is lockdata', lockdata)
    ...
}
```